# how to add two random string from if statements

Tags: python

I am trying to make a word generator type thing, where it takes a random number of constonant and vowels based on the users input and makes a word. However I have it all working except im not sure how to combine them at the end so that it shows them in one group.

```
import random

num_of_cons = input("how many constants do you want in the word: 1-3(a), 4-7(b), 7-10(c)? ")
num_of_vows = input("how many vowels do you want in the word: 1-3(a), 3-5(b)? ")

vowels = ("a", "e","i", "o","u")
constants = ("b","c","d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p")


if num_of_cons == "a":
    print(random.sample(constants, random.randint(1,3)))

elif num_of_cons =="b":
    print(random.sample(constants, random.randint(4,7)))
    
elif num_of_cons == "c":
    print(random.sample(constants, random.randint(7,10)))
  
else:
   pass
    

if num_of_vows == "a":
    print(random.sample(vowels, random.randint(1,3)))
else:
     print(random.sample(vowels, random.randint(3,5)))
```

this is how it comes out after it run but with different letters each time.

```
['k', 'j', 'm']
['a', 'u', 'i']
```

Comment: Replace `print(random.sample(constants, random.randint(1,3)))` with `print(''.join(random.sample(constants, random.randint(1,3))))`, and likewise replace other print values.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @j1-lee yeah i would like it to combine the vowels and constonants like "kjmaui" for example. rather than them being seperated.

Comment: So the desired output would be "kajumi"? If so, consider the case where there are a different number of cons and vows, its not clear how you would want to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import random

num_of_cons = input("how many constants do you want in the word: 1-3(a), 4-7(b), 7-10(c)? ")
num_of_vows = input("how many vowels do you want in the word: 1-3(a), 3-5(b)? ")

vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
constants = ("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p")

if num_of_cons == "a":
    print(''.join(random.sample(constants, random.randint(1, 3))))

elif num_of_cons == "b":
    print(''.join(random.sample(constants, random.randint(4, 7))))

elif num_of_cons == "c":
    print(''.join(random.sample(constants, random.randint(7, 10))))

else:
    pass

if num_of_vows == "a":
    print(''.join(random.sample(vowels, random.randint(1, 3))))
else:
    print(''.join(random.sample(vowels, random.randint(3, 5))))
```